# Totally offline app-SQlite-show POIS

Tags: sqlite, android-studio, osmdroid

Can i use osmdroid to save my offline maps in a sqlite db and after show offline some POIS and get distances beetween my location and the location of the POIS?
From a research i figure out that osmdroid not support offline searching for POIS. Is that true?
  Its better to search for the lip Mapforge?

Answer (score 0):

With osmdroid, you can

- View downloaded, prerendered, map tiles offline via database or several other mechanisms
- Plot icons, lines, polygons, etc and attach on click handers for each item
- Show your location on the map

So that said, you can get the point for a specific item on the map. If you can get your location, then it's a simple equation to calculate straight line distance.

If you want the points to be offline and searchable, you'll need a database of some sort, a way to populate it and some strategy to search it. This is pretty much what mapsforge is doing. I've done similar things with wikimapia data and it can definitely be done, but there's nothing provided out of the box since osmdroid only handles raster images.

If online is an option, osmbonuspack provides a number of drivers to search several online resources for POIs, including turn by turn directions.

Comment: Thank u very much spy.